# Create Campaign - MailChimp API 1.3 - C# Example

Tags: c#, php, api, mailchimp

Hey Guys I'm trying to create a new campaign via the Mail Chimp API (V1.3)

The method I am using is

```
campaignCreate(string apikey, string type, array options, array content, array segment_opts, array type_opts)
```

Documentation found here: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/campaigncreate.func.php

However I'm struggling to find C# Examples of how to use this method.

Essentially I want to tell the API to send a template (already stored in the MC account) to all the users on a given list.

So Far I have this..

```
 var options = new Campaign.Options(listId, "subjecthere", "user@someDomain.com", "From Name Here", "To Name here");
            options.TemplateID = templateId;

            var mailChimpSubscribers = 
_mcApi.CampaignCreate(Campaign.Type.Regular, options, HELP HERE PLEASE)
```

The third argument ('content'-Campaign.Content.Base) -  is what I'm not sure about, I am already specifying a template so I don't need to pass HTML here, according to the documentation...

> If you chose a template instead of pasting in your HTML content, then
>   use "html_" followed by the template sections as keys - for example,
>   use a key of "html_MAIN" to fill in the "MAIN" section of a template.

I have one section inside the template I want to fill in...so this sounds like what I need to do...

anyone got any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the documentation you posted answers your question pretty directly. Find the name of the section in the template you need to provide content for, add it to `html_`, and then pass that as the content argument. In JSON, your request would look like this:

```
{
  ...
  "content": {
    "html_MAIN": "Sweet HTML content for my newsletter here."
  }
}
```

I'm not sure which wrapper library you're using, but that's what you want it to do. For most of them that means passing the struct/dict/hash/associative array from `content` as the right parameter.